# Are static std::map member variables safe in C++?

Tags: c++, static, stdmap

Suppose that I want to implement a kind of lookup table as a `std::map<std::string, int>`, for example:

```
// Utils.hpp header

class Utils
{
public:
    static std::map<std::string, int> NameToId;
   
    static int GetIdForName(const std::string & name)
    {
        auto it = NameToId.find(name);
        if (it != NameToId.end())
            return it->second;
        else
            return -1; // not found
    }
};
```

In the corresponding .cpp file:

```
// Utils.cpp

#include “Utils.hpp”

std::map<std::string, int> Utils::NameToId = {
    {“foo”, 10},
    {“bar”, 20},
    …
};
```

Is it safe to have such a `static std::map` member variable?

Could that cause subtle bugs due to `std::map`’s (and `std::string`) *dynamic* initialization?

If the table is known at compile time and read-only, would it be better/safer to replace the use of `std::map` with something like `std::array<std::pair<std::string_view, int>>`, and use linear search (or binary search if the pairs are sorted by string keys) to look up the integer values associated to strings?

Comment: why would not be safe?

Comment: There is the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof). You should not use the map from other static stuff that runs before `main`.

Comment: TLDR: What you have is safe.

Comment: @teapot418 - I'd augment your statement with "from other static stuff defined in a different source file".

Comment: FWIW I've seen bugs because of that in production. I've removed such a static member from the redis++ client, maybe the [wording in my commit](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/commit/24ff8d17751d28ae8b93d7e683e1cf00372f1396) is not the best but you can take a look. A user would have to write quirky code to or have malicious intent to make it happen, but certainly doable. Thank God for address sanitizer because when such stuff happens in multithreaded code there's little hope to untangle the mess

Comment: Why is `NameToId` not `const`? Should/could it be in your case? Because it likely changes the answer

Comment: @ildjarn: I edited the question and added a note on the special case of read-only lookup table known at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bug I fixed in the [redis client](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/commit/24ff8d17751d28ae8b93d7e683e1cf00372f1396):

A client class can create subscriber objects (you need a client object to create subscribers):

```cpp
class Client {

public:

  Subscriber subscriber() { ... }
};
```

The subscriber contains such an (unordered but same thing) static map:

```cpp
class Subscriber {
public: 
  static std::map<...> table; 
}
```

Now the fun starts when you combine two things:

1. Create a static global client (I didn't say bugs happen by following best practices)
2. Make sure that a method of the `Client` class uses `Subscriber::table` to do some lookup (because we don't like `switch` and `if else`). Well actually it uses a static method of `Subscriber` and that use the static member but anyways...

What you have in order of initialization-destruction is

1. Create client
2. Create subscriber
3. Destroy subscriber
4. Destroy client

Right there between step 3 and 4, the client may have some queue of unprocessed messaged and by the time it gets to process them it will have to use a dead static property. The client and the static member all live in global space and we just happened to initialize the client before the subscriber static member.

Mix that in with the fact that a client may have multiple subscribers operating in parallel (to be fair there was a thread running until stuff was processed so the Client object had to process leftover data before the destructor could complete - if no async computation delayed the destructor the bug was non observable) and you have a really nice way of loosing your mind over sanitizer reports. Enjoy

---

**Verdict** : What you have is not bulletproof. Be really careful on how that static may be used or accessed outside the class. If only non static methods use it, the bug I describe above cannot happen. If public static methods use it, or if the member itself is public be suspicious of how it mixes with other static objects.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I was thinking of those kinds of subtle interactions, like the one you described: the code starts simple, then different components are added and they interact with each others and with their static methods and member variables, and subtle bugs can happen.

Comment: @Mr.C64 Since you mention `std::array` + linear runtime search as alternatives, note that in the [related commit](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/pull/306#discussion_r773918792) I included a `switch` on strings example as a suggestion